# mu4e smart refiling to variable maildir

Tags: mu4e

Mu4e documentation has an example of [smart refiling](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Smart-refiling.html), whereby you can choose which maildir to refile an email based on the properties of that email. I'd like to do that, except the destination maildir's name is a property of the email (specifically the :to property).

Probably easiest to explain in an example. In the documentation:

```lisp
(setq mu4e-refile-folder
  (lambda (msg)
    (cond
      ;; messages to the mu mailing list go to the /mu folder
      ((mu4e-message-contact-field-matches msg :to
     "mu-discuss@googlegroups.com")
    "/mu")
    ;; ........[ SNIP ]
 )))
```

In this example all emails to a googlegroups `mu-discuss@googlegroups.com` end up in the `/mu` maildir. I'd like to go one further. I'd like `%anything%@googlegroups.com` to go to the maildir `/googlegroups/%anything%`, for any value of `%anything%`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what a ride into the world of elisp. I think I got it so that it works, well enough for my modest needs anyway (don't care about cross-posting, case differences etc). As with most things, you get more responses on SE by posting code than with an open-ended question such as I did originally, and I am happy to improve upon this snippet with suggestions. This really is my first non-toy function I've ever created in elisp.

Massive props to the creators or mu4e and s.el. Both these packages are beautifully documented and made the learning experience a heck of a lot more pleasant.

You will need the [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) package for `s-suffix?`, `s-downcase` (not that it's strictly needed), and `s-chop-suffix`

```lisp
(defun personal/refile-maildir (msg)
  "Refile based on a message's characteristics"
  (let*
      ((to-addresses (mu4e-message-field msg :to))
       (maillist-addr  (cl-find-if
                        (lambda (to) (s-suffix? "@googlegroups.com" (cdr to)))
                        to-addresses)))
    (cond
     (maillist-addr
        (concat "/googlegroups." (s-chop-suffix "@googlegroups.com" (s-downcase (cdr maillist-addr)))))
       (t "/Archive"))))
```

Guaranteed there are cuter answers out there so I will not mark this question as solved for a while, in case anyone wants to chip in with a better solution.